# Deriving a many-use key for symmetric data encryption

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, key, aes

I need to generate a 256 bit key for AES symmetric encryption in .net. I have not found any description on how to do so "from scratch". By this I mean, I don't intend to base this key off of a user password. I simply want to produce a cryptographically secure key to use.

The best option, as far as I can tell, is simply to use the .net class [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

Is this the best approach to generate cryptographically secure keys?

Comment: Another comment: normally many-use or single-use is not so much applicable for the key generation. It has more to do *how* you use the key. E.g. if you use CBC encryption with a static IV, you should not use a key multiple times. In other words, the keys properties are identical, it's how you handle them that makes the difference.

Comment: (1) changed the language a bit to make that more clear (2) by "many use" I just mean that I will be using the key for multiple encryptions with multiple IV's. So my impression was that that was the appropriate term. Thanks

Comment: Many-use is certainly the correct term, it just does not make a difference for how the key should be generated.

Comment: Are you clear on what IV is used for?  In cumulative cipher modes IV is just used for the initial block, then following blocks use the remainder from encrypting that block.  But if you're using a small value like a credit card and you're using a 256 bit key, then the entire extra randomization comes from the IV, and using a stream cipher with a text only one block long is really no better than using ECB.

Comment: A good strategy for security is to have most of your key the same from request to request.  Fill in part of the key value with a value from the server registry or something else outside of the code base.  Consider using a per-user IV, and/or salting the base key with a per user value (pre-pending the user id to the key for example).  The "something from the server" helps so that if someone got your database and your code they wouldn't be able to decrypt your fields.

Comment: My impression was that using a block cipher (AES) in a CTR mode (I used GCM) utilizes the IV to prevent 2 congruent plaintext blocks from becoming congruent cipher text blocks. And if I am encrypting small blocks what mode should I be using?

Comment: And I am fairly certain that using AES in CTR mode with small blocks is secure provided you never repeat the IV. Why do you believe it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best approach" depends on your exact requirements.

If all you require is 32 random bytes, then RNGCryptoServiceProvider is fine.  You have to make arrangements to ensure that the key is available at your destination, typically using RSA or some other asymmetric encryption method.  If you need it for archive purposes, then you will need a way to securely store it.  You also need to ensure that it is securely deleted after you no longer need it.

Alternatively you could use a [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), with the same considerations of transfer, storage and deletion applying to the KDF parameters.

Comment: Could you please explain how using asymmetric encryption gets the key to the destination securely?

Comment: Asymmetric encryption has a public key and a private key.  These must be set up in advance.  The useful part is that the public key need not be kept secret.  The less useful part is that it is usually a lot slower than symmetric encryption, hence the technique of using it for a small key, rather than a large data file.  Encrypt your key, using the destination's public key.  They will be able to decrypt it, using their private key.  There are many descriptions on the internet, and on stackoverflow.